# Why is the Titans tower not T-shaped in the Titans TV show on DC Universe?

Tags: production, titans

In the cartoons, the Titans Tower is T-shaped.

In the DC Universe TV show *Titans*, it's just a normal building owned by Bruce Wayne.

I understand that it's not always possible to translate everything from cartoon to live-action.

Is it really difficult to create such a building using special effects or create a set that resembles a T-shaped building?

Comment: In the DC Universe TV show, everything plays in just that apartment. I always thought that they refer to it as Titans Tower as they its an apartment in a tower that is used by the Titans

Answer (score 4):

### Because that's what the showrunners/producers wanted.

> One of the decisions made early on involved abandoning the traditional T-shaped building design for one that blends into the San Francisco skyline. Jurek [*production designer Ingrid Jurek*] said,
>
> > **"Our Tower was not meant to be the T-shape on an island that's basically hiding in plain sight in downtown San Francisco with a view of the bay.** That's where we ended up in the beginning, because again, it's a drama about superheroes, rather than holding close to the comics, although there are some things I think are close enough."
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://uk.ign.com/articles/2019/09/12/titans-season-2-brings-titans-tower-to-life-on-dc-universe-ign-first)</sup>